# Маршрутизация UDP пакетов в linux

Tags: linux, iptables, маршрутизация

На сервер linux приходят UDP пакеты.

Есть обновляющийся список, вроде

"IP отправителя":"Port отправителя":"Port, на который нужно переадресовывать пакеты на локальном сервере"

Как это можно реализовать?

Создавать для каждой строки в списке правило в iptables, и при изменении строки - изменять правило?

Comment: Ну в общем виде да, добавлять/модифицировать/удалять правила iptables. А дальше уже в зависимости от количества правил решать в одну таблицу пишем или делаем разветвленную структуру таблиц

Comment: @Mike, правила **netfilter-а**. а iptables — это программа для манипуляции этими правилами. // автору вопроса: *upd* — это опечатка?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо. Исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i {IN_INTERFACE} -d {IN_INTERFACE_IP} --dport {IN_INTERFACE_PORT} -j DNAT --to-destination {TO_DESTINATION_IP:PORT}`

Этим правилом можно перенаправлять траффик. К примеру

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 1003 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:1004`

по этому правилу траффик придя на интерфейс `eth0`, source address `192.168.1.2` и порт `1003` будет перенаправлен на адрес `192.168.1.2` и порт `1004`.

Можно легко найти скрипт на баше, который будет по крону читать ваш файл с адресами построчно и добавлять этим правила. Только не забывайте перед запуском вашего скрипта удалять прошлые правила, iptables их не заменяет, только добавляет.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы описали, называется NAT (Network Address Translation).
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT